# Using JAXB annotated class for a JAXWS service

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

i have a web service working like this:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "TempService")
public class TempService {
  @WebMethod(operationName = "addBarkod")
  public Boolean addBarkod(@WebParam(name = "barkod") Barkod barkod) {
    System.out.println(barkod.getBarkodNo());
  }
}
```

and the Barkod class as:

```
public class Barkod {
  private String barkodNo;
// there are constructors and getters, setters etc. nothing fancy //
}
```

with this structure my web service can be called with soapUI wtihout a problem. the problem is when i want to annotate my model class with JAXB annotations like:

```
@XmlType(name="barkod")
@XmlRootElement(name="barkod")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
```

i can deploy this to glassfish 3.1 and soapUI generates new client request with new structure but when it comes to do "barkod.getBarkodNo();" at addBarkod operation it throws a NullPointerException. i looks like the XML i sent to the web service does not create a proper Barkod object.

do i have to do with web service class or something?

Comment: Can you post the exception you are getting?

Comment: i just paste it: https://gist.github.com/2359811

Comment: What is null at `TempService.java:54` to cause the NPE?

Comment: at my TempService class i have a method called addBarkod that takes an argument of Barkod class. at that point i am trying to do barkod.getBarkodNo() . without JAXB annotations it works fine. but when i want to customize XML represantation and use JAXB annotations it throws NPE

Comment: Have you been able to narrow down to which JAXB annotation causes it to fail?

Comment: eg i used just @XmlRootElement annotation on my Barkod class (a very simple java class) and it throws the NPE. without any JAXB annotations it works well.

Comment: may be you can direct me a simple jaxws service example that an operation uses a jaxb annotated class type as an argument or return value.

Comment: I would suggest you to use `-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true` on the server to see what actually comes in. If the XML request looks complete, just post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think problem caused because soapUI generates the request automatically from my WSDL. when i annotate my class with @XmlRootElement without the namespace clause it does not map given XML to may object. i assign @XmlRootElemen(namespace="") and my problem goes away.

thanks for responses anyway.